# Como verificar o consumo de bateria dos sensores de um dispositivo?

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para Android, na qual eu vou utilizar os sensores embarcados (por exemplo, GPS e Acelerômetro) dos dispositivos móveis, só que antes eu preciso fazer os teste dos consumo desses sensores, pois a economia de energia dos dispositivos móveis é o meu objetivo. Gostaria de saber se existe algum aplicativo que verifica o consumo de energia dos sensores embarcados?

Answer (score 5):

Talvez o mais indicado para o seu caso seja o [PowerTutor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.umich.PowerTutor&hl=pt_BR), ele mede de forma detalhada o consumo de bateria, inclusive com alguns gráficos para análise.

A partir do **Android 5.0**, também é possível utilizar um comando via adb para descarregar toda utilização da bateria:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats > dump.txt
```

Esse comando vai gerar um arquivo `dump.txt` com todo o relatório de uso da bateria.